# How can I detect whether an app was launched from Home screen or System Tray?

Tags: android

Is there a way to know whether an application
was launched from Home screen (where it was kept as a short cut)
or from the System tray (where it exists with all other apps) ?

Comment: I think `onResume()` will be called first when you launch application from system tray.

Comment: No, I don't think so. onresume() is simply called when the instance of app already exists on the stack and is being relaunched. If instance does not exist on stack, oncreate() is called.

Comment: What do you mean by System tray? Is it like when you hold the home button for long time and list of open apps appear?